# Full screen on many screen (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, fullscreen

I'm using WPF

I would like that my windows take the entire screen of all the screen.

If I use the code snippet :

```
WindowState = WindowState.Normal;  
WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;  
Topmost = true;  
WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

it takes only the active screen.
How to fill all the screen ?

thanks for your help

Comment: How will you handle oddly shaped configurations like mine (the two screens don't share a top/bottom edge even).

Comment: Finally, I've done something where I calculate the min and the max of all screens, and I create a window of this size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximized window state only fills one screen. That's how windows work in Windows.

You can either create a separate window for every display, or use a single window position it at the lowest x/y coordinates for all displays and resize it so you fill up every display. You would have to keep note on where the screens are on your window surface, though, since there are display configurations you wouldn't expect, such as the following one:

```
        ┌──────┐
        │      │
        │      │
        │      │ ┌──────────┐
        │      │ │          │
        └──────┘ │          │
    ┌───────┐    │          │
    │       │    │          │
    │       │    │          │
    │       │    └──────────┘
    │       │
    └───────┘
```

Entirely possible and a pain to handle if you only expect rectangular setups.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help
I will create as windows as screen.

Best regards